# Partial fractions with 2 squared terms

Tags: partial-fractions

Attempting the following partial fraction equation and was wondering how to approach the $s^2$ outside the brackets:
$$\frac{1}{s^2(s^2+2s+10)}$$

Comment: In what problem did you encounter this? Maybe we have a better method of solving it that doesn't involve this. See also [How to ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The question asks to find the inverse laplace transform of the above equation.

Comment: They're not "terms", but "factors."  And they're different.  One is an irreducible quadratic.  The other is a linear squared.  If it were written $(s-0)^2$, you might not have been confused(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{s^2(s^2+2s+10)}=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{s^2}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+2s+10}$$

Now, just cross-multiply and get the values of $A,B,C,D$ in the usual way.

Comment: would you use a similiar method if the 1 was substituted for $e^{-s}$?

Comment: Sure. For $e^{-s}$ Laplace inverse would be just $f(t-1)$ in time domain shift.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the help given by @Your IDE and the answer will be:

$$\frac{s-3}{50 \left(s^2+2 s+10\right)}+\frac{1}{10 s^2}-\frac{1}{50 s}$$